# Array is undefined in For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get the following error (which doesn't make any sense to me !!):

```
TypeError: jImages[i] is undefined
```

Code:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'FilterByToestanden.php',
         data: {aantal: $("#aantToestanden option:selected").text(), tekst: $('#bevat').val()},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(data) {
                      var jImages = JSON.parse(data);
                      alert(jImages[0][0]);
                      var filteredImageList = new Array();
                      for (var i=0, len = data.length; i< len; i++)
                      {
                      filteredImageList[i]=jImages[i][0]+jImages[i][1];
                      }
                      alert(filteredImageList);
                  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.length` should be `jImages.length`.

`data.length` is the length of the JSON string, which is much more than the length of the `jImages` array. So you were going beyond the end of the array, resulting in trying to access undefined elements.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work otherwise, but it works now ! thanks

Comment: You must be totally clueless if you don't understand the difference, but I added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

data is a string (JSON string), and jImages is a 2d array. In general data.length (string character number) is different from jImages (number of elements inside the array).

you should do something like:

```
for (var i=0, len = jImages.length; i< len; i++)
```